# Поиск по нескольким полям с одинаковыми значениями в пределах одной таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Приветствую всех. Имеется следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TYPE ref AS ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
CREATE TABLE table1(id SERIAL, param1 INTEGER, param2 ref, param3 VARCHAR(64), param4 VARCHAR(64));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SOMEINDEX ON table1 (param1,param2,param3);
```

Примерные значения **table1**:

```
id |param1 | param2 |  param3 | param 4
======================================
 1 |   0   |   a    |   sss   |  ttt
 2 |   1   |   a    |   sss   |  ttt
 3 |   0   |   b    |   nnn   |  hhh
 4 |   2   |   a    |   sss   |  ttt
 5 |   1   |   b    |   fff   |  fff
 6 |   0   |   c    |   ccc   |  mmm
 7 |   0   |   b    |   ttt   |  rrr
 8 |   1   |   b    |   nnn   |  hhh
 9 |   2   |   b    |   nnn   |  hhh
10 |   0   |   a    |   ccc   |  zzz
11 |   1   |   a    |   ccc   |  zzz
12 |   2   |   a    |   ccc   |  zzz
```

**param1** - может быть любым значением integer

требуется выбрать **param3**,**param4**, которые *имеются во всех записях **param1** с заранее известным **param2** (например, *WHERE param2='a'*)

В итоге надо получить:

если **WHERE param2='a'**

```
param3 | param4
================
 sss   |  ttt
 ccc   |  zzz
```

если **WHERE param2='b'**

```
param3 | param4
===============
 nnn   |  hhh
```

Как составить SQL-запрос для такого выбора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это?

```
select param3,param4 from table1
where param2='a'
group by param3,param4
having count(*) = (select count(distinct param1) from table1 where param2='a');
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `HAVING` со сравнением количества отличающихся значений `param1`:

```
SELECT param2, param3, param4 FROM table1 WHERE param2 = 'b'
GROUP BY param2, param3, param4
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT param1) = (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT param1) FROM table1 WHERE param2 = 'b'
)
```